# Font-size relative to body?

Tags: css, font-size

Is there any way I can have font-sizes relative to the body font-size setting?

I know I could use percentages like this:

```
body{
  font-size: 14px;
}


p{
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

But this produces unwanted results on nested elements, where the font-size becomes relative to the parent element:

```
li{
  font-size: 150%;
}

li li{
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS3 introduced `rem`(root em), which is html.  Unlike em, which sets the unit relative to the parent font-size, `rem` will set the unit relative to the root.  Here is a great article on rem: [>>>CLICK HERE<<<](http://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/)

CSS:

```
html {
    font-size: 14px;
}

p {
    font-size: 21px;   /*cross browser fall-back hack*/
    font-size: 1.5rem; /*same as 150%*/        
}

li {
    font-size: 21px;   /*cross browser fall-back*/
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
li li {
    font-size:18px;    /*cross browser fall-back*/
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

For cross browser compatibility concerns, you can use a fall-back by also including px for desired results.

I am adding my response to Jukka K. Korpela's comment, as I think it is relevant to the original post.

The functionality of rem is an attempt to remove the compounding effect of em/% throughout your document (especially in lists) and also gain elasticity that you do not get with px.  em/% requires a great deal of maintenance and with the ever evolving internet environment, this means a-lot of time.  Additionally early IE would still require a hack to set the base percentage (most commonly the root [HTML] to 100%) then set the parent element to the necessary size.  However, this hack would cause issues with newer browsers that follow the cascade properly.  Again, my recommendation is to use rem for the a flexibility and ease of maintenance and a fall-back (for unsupported browsers) of px.

Comment: The `rem` unit is relative to the root element font size, not the `body` element. Using `px` is a wrong fallback – if it were OK, why use relative units in the first place? For real compatibility, use `em` or `%`, with due calculations.

Comment: The body element is a typo, it was supposed to be html, so thank you for recognizing this mistake.   As far as your response to the fall-back, I completely disagree with you and please read my edited original post.

Comment: @Alex - rem is based on the root [html] value.  When an html size is omitted the rem will assume the default value of 16px. In your example, you used a rem of 1.5 for the #one li elements and percentage of 150% for the #two li elements which is getting its base value from the body font-size of 18px.  And enter the compounding issue.  The way your #two li font-size is interpreted is all li elements with an id of two will have a 150% font-size (of its parent element).

Comment: @Alex - Now stepping through the example, #two li will have a value of 27px (body 18px X 150% = 27px).  The #two li li will have a value of 40.5px (two li 27px X 150% = 40.5px) and #two li li li will have a value of 60.75px (two li li 40.5px X 150% = 60.75px).  There are workarounds for the compounding of em/% usage, like setting all the child elements to to 100% or 1em.

Comment: @Alex - To get the rem to hit its mark, set your HTML value to 18px and then use rem in the rest of your document.  Again, I recommend using a px based fall-back for browsers that do not support rem.

Comment: Here is an updated JSFiddle sample with the use of rem:  http://jsfiddle.net/4S6EG/1/

Comment: ok i didn't realize 16px was the default. setting the font-size on the html element is fine

Answer (score 2):

When using relative values, such as `font-size: 150%;` this is relative to the parent element. You can't change that.

For example if you had:

```
<div>
  <p id=p1>
    <p id=p2>
      <p id=p3>
         ...
```

With this CSS:

```
div { font-size: 10pt }
p   { font-size: 200% }
```

The result would be p1 would have a font size of 20pt, p2 would be 40pt, p3 would be 8-pt and so on.

You could get around this by overriding the font-size of everything, and then doing a relative font-size on only the relevant elements such as:

```
*    { font-size: 100% }
body { font-size: 10pt }
#p3  { font-size: 150% }
div  { font-size: 120% }
```

But again, any nesting of elements, like `<div>`s in the above example would again cause the relative font-size to grow or shrink with each nesting.

Comment: Just restating the problem is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your case is to switch to the use of variables and compile your css in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Although, if you don't want to go over the trouble, you can rely on %, em, or javascript...

Answer (score 0):

The **absolute unit**, the pixel, is used if you want absolute control or in case you need a "pixel perfect" result. On the other hand, **the relative units**, like **em** or **rem** are usually used if the font size needs to change according to the screen size. It provides easier manipulation and requires fewer media query usages.

The **em** unit is relative to the parent font-size, while the **rem** unit is relative to the root element.

Here is an example of the usage of the **rem** unit:

```
html { font-size: 100% } //usually this is 16px

p, 
div {
  font-size: 1rem; //this will equal to 16px
}


section, 
article  {
  font-size: 1.5rem; //this will equal to 24px
}
```

There is a great article here https://kolosek.com/css-relative-font-size/ that explains the absolute and relative font sizes in detail.